# Making Hostile Animals Friendly

Tags: dnd-5e, animals, social-combat

#### Background

I want to make myself a homebrew system to better deal with how to reward experience points to my players for roleplay, spellcasting, and combat respectively rather than just the 1 experience bar that gives limited rewards as you level. I want to create a better system where the results of my players actions are better reflected than a basic standard number.  This question has to do with wild animals (beasts).

#### Actual Question

What are the stages between a hostile animal and a tame animal?

What are the requirements to go from each stage to the next?

For example: You encounter a wild animal in the woods that is clearly agitated. What mechanics and DCs are involved in trying to take said animal and make it more friendly towards you and to calm it down? Being able to order and command it in combat would be a much longer process than just calming it down and making it more friendly towards you, but I want to know what is that process too and what are each of the stages of that process.

I know somewhere there are official guidelines for this, but I just can’t find them. I’m not looking for the Ranger/Druid specific abilities or the spells that do this, I'm looking for a nonmagical way anyone can attempt to do this.

Comment: Related (closed) question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120468/43856

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that experience points are actually optional in 5e?

Comment: @enkryptor I am not a fan of chapter leveling at all as I feel it takes away from the appeal to roleplay when you are only going to level when you reach a certain checkpoint. I prefer experience points as it motivates my players to do more rather than just only focus on the plot they explore and interact with npc's to enjoy the world and people I created for them. 2nd off,

Comment: the homebrew system im creating is in effort to try and make a better system than chapter leveling or experience points and have in be based on logical in game sense and have the rewards you get be a better reflection on the actions you took to reach the point you are at.

Comment: How 5e with its levels is supposed to be related to this "better system"?

Comment: The background was what prompted the actual question, but to answer you, essentially my idea is to divide experience into 3 different areas. 1) Physical. Any combat that isn't a spell, skill checks & sv throws that aren't related to magic, would contribute towards your main xp bar that would determine when you gain hit dice, additional health, and class abilites

Comment: 2) Spellcaster levels. This would indicate your ability to cast spells and use magical objects without instruction. Any SV against magic, skill checks involving magic, spells cast, magical objects used or magical areas interacted with would contribute xp to a separate experience bar that when leveled would give you additional spells, increase general knowledge of magic and your effective ability to use magical items and interact with magical areas.

Comment: 3) Social. This last one is my reason for asking this and another question on this forum as for instead of using an experience bar, any rp you do with npcs effects your reputation in a certain area for better or for worse and does the same for each individual person you interact with.

Comment: I mean, do you really stuck with 5e? Is the [dnd-5e] tag relevant here? For instance, the Pathfinder system has strict (yet more complicated) rules about social interactions along with specific degrees on the "hostility/friendliness" scale. 5e doesn't have such a thing, leaving it to the narrative part (read "to the DM").

Comment: Every single experience I have ever had with Pathfinder is arguably some of the worst experiences I've had in my years of playing in rpgs, so I tend to stick to D&D 5E, 3.5 when a party wants that edition. I haven't delved into the pathfinder system more deeply due to the bad taste I've gotten from each experience with it. Nothing against the Pathfinder system itself, just always getting worse and worse experiences whenever I participate in a game using that system has pushed me away from it

Answer (score 5):

## Up to the DM

There are no official general guidelines, as far as I know, for that mechanic. The only non-magical thing anyone can attempt is the skill Animal Handling (Wisdom).

As any other skill, it's treated mostly as a binary result - either you fail that skill, or you pass that skill check. Note that, by the PHB, Animal Handling **can only be used to calm down domesticated animals**. Allowing anyone befriend a wild, hostile animal would make Animal Friendship a lot worse (and it's already not amazing).

One example of using that for calming down seemingly wild animals is given in the Lost Mine of Phandelver adventure from the starter set (spoiler ahead)

> In the first dungeon described in the book, there is a kennel with 3 wolves. Anyone can try to calm them down with a DC 15 Animal Handling check. If you give them food, the DC is reduced to 10 instead.

Again, it depends - somehow - on the animal itself. A hungry wolf might be calmed down by giving it food, while a bear trying to protect its little baby-bear might be calmed down by simply walking away and showing, somehow, you are not there to harm their child.

Similar to my answer in your [other, similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124706/43856), it depends on the NPC's (and here I'm saying NPC as any character, including animals) motivations and personalities for the encounter.

Comment: I was told to separate my question into 2 despite them being similar.

Comment: @KaleDodge I do think they are better separated, as the way to role-play animals is different from how you role-play humanoids. The ability checks are also (arguably) different, in particular some Charisma checks should change to Wisdom here. The questions (and thus the answers) are obviously similar and related, though.